# Can't raze a captured city in Civilization 4

Tags: civilization-4

I am having a strange issue.

I just captured the last city of an AI opponent. Usually, when I capture a city, I will be given an option to either install a governor or to raze it.

However, for this particular city, I was given only "Yes! Install a new Governor..." and "Wait, let me examine the city first...", but **no option to raze the city**.

What gives? Is it because the city is the last city of that defeated civilization?

I really don't want to take the city... it is surrounded by the ocean; only 5 usable tiles in the 'fat cross'.

Comment: Was this city there capital?

Comment: @CyanAngel well, yes, since it's their last city...

Comment: Gah, I had a complete answer ready, and then notices this is civ 4 and not civ 5. And I don't know the mechanic in civ 4

Comment: @Arperum well, some mechanics are similar... Is it not possible to raze a Capital in Civ5?

Comment: @Arperum I just realised the same thing. @ pepoluan Civ5 has a victory condition that is "Capture All Capitals"

Comment: civ V also doesn't let you raze the original capital of a city for some specific reason (a valid one). I didn't know civ IV had this too, since it lacks the mechanic that is the reason in civ V.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From recollection<sup>1</sup>, you cannot raze a city in Civilization 4 if:

- City razing is turned off as a game option
- Your team's culture makes up more than 25%<sup>2</sup> of total culture in the city

Short answer, but that's it. Note that you can still *"disband"* cities acquired through cultural flips.

<sub>[1] Later confirmed via `acquireCity()` and `canRaze()` in `CvPlayer.cpp`

[2] `RAZING_CULTURAL_PERCENT_THRESHOLD` in `GlobalDefines.xml`</sub>

Comment: Ah, thanks! The first cause is definitely not it, as I can raze other cities. Most likely it was due to the second cause. Let me see if I still have the save prior to the turn when I capture the city...

Comment: Ah, found the save just before I launch the raid. Strange... my civ's culture level is just 8%...

Comment: Permanent alliance or team game?

Comment: I'm also not sure about how the sequence of events goes when a civ is *eliminated* - I don't care to delve that deeply into the source code. Total culture **does** exclude culture of dead civilizations (though its saved, so if they ever become alive again somehow, their culture comes back). So if the civ is set as dead first before the check, then you might have more than 25% of total culture afterwards. Speculation here.

Comment: Hmm... maybe that's the reason (civ is set dead, _then_ %culture calculated). Oh well, I'll just have to live with it :-/ ... thanks for the answer attempt! I'll checkmark yours.